# Make a specific Sum<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `Contract` with inside an `ObservableCollection<Repere>`:

```
class Contract : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Repere> listReperes;
    public ObservableCollection<Repere> ListReperes
    {
        get { return listReperes; }
        set
        {
            listReperes = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listReperes, value); //NotifyPropertyChanged("ListReperes");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My class 'Repere' has an `ObservableCollection<Operation>`

```
class Repere : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Operation> listOperations;
    public ObservableCollection<Operation> ListOperations
    {
        get { return listOperations; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listOperations, value);

        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, my class Operation is as the following :

```
public class Operation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int qtyFinished;
    public int QtyFinished
    {
        get { return qtyFinished; }
        set
        {
            qtyFinished = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("QtyFinished");
        }
    }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My contract has a list of Repere, and Each Repere has inside a list of operations,what I want is to group my Repere by name, and get the total list of Operation for each Repere.

For now I do the following :

```
List<Repere> liste_rep_group = liste_rep.GroupBy(l => l.Name)
    .Select(cl => new Repere
    {
        Quantite = cl.Sum(c => c.TotalQuantity),
        TotalQuantity = cl.Sum(c => c.TotalQuantity),
        ID = -1,
        IdAff = cl.First().IdAff,
        Name = cl.First().Name,
        NameOri = cl.First().Name,
        Nom_aff = cl.First().Nom_aff,
        Profil = cl.First().Profil,
        Longueur = cl.First().Longueur,
        Hauteur = cl.First().Hauteur,
        Largeur = cl.First().Largeur,
        Poids = cl.First().Poids,
        Priorite = cl.Min(c => c.Priorite),
        ListOperations = new ObservableCollection<Operation>(),
    }).ToList();
```

And as I don't know how to "sum" the ListOperations, I then do it manually

```
foreach (Repere rep in liste_rep)
{
    Repere repFound = liste_rep_group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == rep.Name);
    if (repFound != null)
    {
        foreach (Operation op in rep.ListOperations)
        {

            Operation opFound = repFound.ListOperations.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == op.ID);
            if (opFound != null)
            {
                opFound.QtyFinished += op.QtyFinished;
                opFound.QtyTot += op.QtyTot;
            }
            else
            {
                Operation newOp = new Operation();
                newOp.Nom = op.Nom;
                newOp.ID = op.ID;
                newOp.Clone(op);
                repFound.ListOperations.Add(newOp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is :

- Group my ObservableCollection by Repere name.
- Sum the list of operations for each Repere with same name

The sum may work like that:

```
public ObservableCollection<Operation> Sum(operation1, operation2)
{
   ObservableCollection<Operation> mySum=new ObservableCollection<Operation>();
   if(operation1.ID==operation2.ID)
   {
      operation1.QtyFinished+=operation2.QtyFinished;
      mySum.Add(operation1);
      return mySum;
   }
   else
   {
      mySum.Add(operation1);
      mySum.Add(operation2);
      return mySum;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to define in my Operation class, a Sum function where I would define how to sum my ObservableCollection?

Edit : Here is an example as requested:

If I want to sum 2 Repere, the result summing operations will be something like that :

```
Repere1
   ID_operation      Quantity
   1                 2
   2                 1
   3                 5
Repere1
   ID_operation      Quantity
   1                 2
   2                 1
   4                 2
```

Result will be :

```
Repere1

   ID_operation      Quantity
   1                 4
   2                 2
   3                 5
   4                 2
```

EDIT :

Ok, all is working fine, just need to change it for ObservableCollection :

```
ListOperations = new ObservableCollection<Operation>(cl.SelectMany(g=>g.ListOperations).GroupBy(o=>o.ID)
                .Select(go => new Operation
                    {
                        ID = go.First().ID,
                        QtyFinished = go.Sum(o => o.QtyFinished),
                        Color=go.First().Color,
                    }))
```

Comment: I'd remove the `set` option for those collections completely, and only provide the `get`. The `set` is likely not doing what you think, and you can still add/remove items from the collection with just the `get`. The `set` is only needed if you want to replace the _entire collection reference_.

Comment: @lesscode No, in fact I made a mistake on the post, it has been edited

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn for which collections? I use to leave the set, because I sometime modify these values, if I understood correctly MVVM, the set is here to update automatically my view if I modify these parameters?(excuse me but I am new on MVVM so maybe I didn't understand correctly)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "modify these parameters". You can still add or remove items from a collection property with just a `get`. You don't need a `set` for that. You only need a `set` if you want to assign a whole new collection instance to the property.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what I mean is the quantities of operations for example can be modified, and when it is modified I need to automatically update the values in my view. same as for Repere, I can edit its geometries(and this influence on quantity of operations), and these values may be updated everytime I make a modify.`a whole new collection instance to the property`:didn't understand that part

Comment: Is it essential that your "summed" results come in the form of `Repere` and `Operation` objects? You might have better clarity if you focus on the actual summed values you need. Can you post an example of the input data and expected output?

Comment: Joel is right in that it's not usual (and quite inefficient) to replace an entire `ObservableCollection` in this way. Assuming you're using WPF, the `ObservableCollection` itself has full change notification implemented (for the collection itself). The items within the collection should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for changes to properties on the items themselves.

Comment: @lesscode I edited question with one example, hope it will be easy to understand

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have no doubt that you are right about unnecessary set, but to be honnest I began programming C# 2 years ago, and MVVM a year ago, so I don't master yet all...

Comment: @lesscode all items have `InotifyPropertyChanged`, I just wrote here manually a part of code and didn't write it(may I do it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
class Repere
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
}

class Operation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<Repere>
        {
            new Repere { Name = "Repere1", Operations = new List<Operation>
            {
                new Operation { Id = 1, Quantity = 2 },
                new Operation { Id = 2, Quantity = 1 },
                new Operation { Id = 3, Quantity = 5 }
            }},
            new Repere { Name = "Repere1", Operations = new List<Operation>
            {
                new Operation { Id = 1, Quantity = 2 },
                new Operation { Id = 2, Quantity = 1 },
                new Operation { Id = 4, Quantity = 2 }
            }},
        };

        var result = data.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
            .Select(gr => new
            {
                Name = gr.Key,
                Operations = gr.SelectMany(g => g.Operations)
                    .GroupBy(o => o.Id)
                    .Select(go => new { Id = go.Key, Quantity = go.Sum(o => o.Quantity)})
            });

        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
            foreach (var o in r.Operations)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{o.Id}\t{o.Quantity}");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to have a setter on `ListOperations` in order for changes to the collection to be properly notified to the UI - the individual items (that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) will raise their own notifications (ie. these won't use the collection's `set` method).

Comment: thanks, I try it right now(didn't know that `SelectMany`), then regarding the `set`, does it have a bad impact if I leave it? As I am not yet familiar enough with Inotify, I got used to put it on all parameters that could be edited by user, and need to update automatically.

Comment: Well, if you leave the setter you or someone else might be tempted to use it... There's very little reason to change out the entire collection, and if you do it will cause the UI to have to throw away it's entire list and rebind to the new collection. What you really want is to just have the UI update as items are added and removed from the collection (without replacing the collection entirely).

Comment: ok, I will take your remark in account, I will first read again some tutorials on it, because before I remove it, I prefer first to understand why(and honestly, until now I didn't understand...)

Comment: Think of it this way - the collection itself is never set by the user, only the items within the collection. The user would (should) never have a way to throw away the entire collection and replace it with an entirely different collection. They may add or remove items, or change existing items, but none of these affect the _identity_ of the collection itself.

Comment: still meet a problem, I put an Edit on my post

Comment: I guess the question becomes _why_ do you need an `ObservableCollection`? What's going to be adding and removing items in that collection?

Comment: Another rule of thumb here would be "If you find yourself typing `new ObservableCollection` anywhere other than as part of a member field declaration or inside a constructor, you're probably doing it wrong".

Comment: yes in fact found it ... and yes you are right, I often have to write `new ObservableCollection`... in that case for example would be no need? (big thanks anyway, with my old method it took 4s, with your formula it takes 300ms to make the same job), I use `new ObservableCollection` everytime I need to load a List<> for example myCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>(myList<T>), is this bad too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187587/discussion-between-siegfried-v-and-lesscode).